Can a Reentrancy Vulnerability Occur When the Check-Effects-Interaction Pattern Is Enforced
I am currently conducting research on reentrancy vulnerabilities in Solidity-based smart contracts, which has led me to the following question:
Can any type of reentrancy vulnerability (single-contract, (read-only) cross-contract, etc.) still occur when the check-effects-interaction pattern is strictly enforced at all times? In other words, can a system still be exploited through reentrancy when its state is always updated before an external call is made?
If yes, could you point me to an example?
If no, why is this pattern not universally enforced by all smart contracts to eliminate the possibility of reentrancy vulnerabilities entirely? Are there scenarios where the check-effects-interaction pattern is not applicable?
